# MongoDb Springboot data loss with docker-compose

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I have a docker docker-compose like this:

```
version: "3"
services:

  api-bug-books-preprod:
    depends_on:
      - mongodb-preprod
    image: bug-books-api:preprod
    restart: always
    container_name: bug-books-preprod
    ports:
      - 9910:9910
    environment:
      SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_HOST: mongodb-preprod
      SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_PORT: 27017
      SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_DATABASE: bug-books-preprod
  mongodb-preprod:
    image: mongo:latest
    container_name: bug-books-mongodb-preprod
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    environment:
       MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: bug-books
   # volumes:
   #   - bug-books-preprod:/data/db

volumes:
  bug-books-preprod:
networks:
  bug-books-preprod:
```

When i run docker compose up -d, all containers run perfectly
On my SpringBoot project I have a command line runer on it
i create 3 default users.

After starting all containers I tried to log in with my default user and the login works perfectly
Everything is working perfectly so far...

> Except that after a few minutes, often 10 minutes, often even up to 30 minutes later, when I try to log in with the same default users the application tells me that its users no longer exist

I've checked the mongo logs and didn't see any deletion request.

[image]
I've seen some ip changes that seem odd to me
for example, in the  image there are two ips, 172 and 94
the last log of 172 is at 23:42 and at that time the login was working with my users.

But the logs with the 94 are from 00:25 and at that time the login no longer worked.

I'm having network problems, maybe I didn't manage the docker compose network properly.

Comment: Do you use Docker Swarm with more nodes? What does `docker container ls -a` and `docker ps -a` say (Are there restarts of container?)? I wouldn't open the `MongoDB`'s ports, then only the `SpringBoot` can access to it via Docker Network and the debugging is much easier (You should see only the `SpringBoot`'s IP in the log). Furthermore, I would put back the persistent volume (the commented part in your example), if you don't use the same container then the data won't be persisted (Somehow can be happened during the restart the container), I don't know if it's a valid scenario in your case.....

Comment: I don't use  Docker Swarm.
docker containers ls -a display an active list of containers and I see my containers in.
I don't know if there are container restarts
I tested with persistent volume but it was the same result.